# Communication between different MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have shortcomings with the implementation of the MVC.

All the examples I have seen are simple: one class for the model and the same for the view and the controller.

How is it done in a real application?

To further clarify my question, let's say I want to create a game that involves placing pieces in a grid.

For the grid I created:

- The model: array (GridModel class)
- View: render the array (GridView class)
- The controller: update the model after user click to place a piece in the grid (GridController class)

For the available pieces

- The model: array of pieces and a a field for the selected piece (`PieceModel` class)
- View: render the array of available pieces (`PieceView` class)
- The controller: update the model: the selected piece (`PieceController` class)

In the part of the grid I need to know the selected piece from the part of available pieces.

My quick solution is to pass a reference from `PieceModel` to `GridView`.

Questions:

1. Do I have to continue in this decomposition or do I have to use a single MVC (considering to add features in the future)?
2. if I need to keep this decomposition, is there a way to ensure communication between different MVC in a proper way than I did in my quick solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based in many stackoverflow questions/Answers about MVC, The model is the group of classs that define the application business logic instead of a simple and unique class as done in exemple and tutorials.

I've changed my structural pattern to the modified MVC where view and model doesn't know any thing about each other.

All communication between both side is handled by the controller, so every controller need to know about Model's classes that are needed by the associated view.

In my exemple : GridController now has a references for both classes (GridModel and PieceModel).

This can create a problem in the future when the number of Model's classes references will grow up  but can be easily solved  by some Factory pattern or Dependency Injection Service.